# Javascript debugging: How to set breakpoint on the actrual event handler code?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, jquery, javascript-debugger

Is there any way to let Chrome Debugger break when run into different Javascript file?

Because I'm debugging an legacy web app, tons of  js file, this feature will help me to find the event handler binded with jquery.click() method.

---

modified: Or simply, how to quickly find the actural event handler code for jquery?

Comment: You could put a breakpoint in the jQuery code and only make it break when the event is a click method?

Comment: This works, but I have to step in, step in, .. many many times... is there any other easier & more generic way?

Comment: Even worse when the jquery is minified, I am having the same problem :(

Comment: @jezternz if jquery minified, there's a boring way: in Chrome Develop tools, right panel of the "Source" tab, there's "Event Listener Breakpoints", check the event you want to debug, then go back to page, trigger that break point, step in, step out, step in, step out ...

Comment: @ColinNiu tried that, possible but still very painful to do. Thanks for idea though.

Answer (score 0):

> You could put a breakpoint in the jQuery code and only make it break when the event is a click method.

> If jQuery minified, there's a boring way: in Chrome DevTools, right panel of the "Source" tab, there's "Event Listener Breakpoints", check the event you want to debug, then go back to page, trigger that break point, step in, step out, step in, step out.

<sup>Source: Answer is based on the comments.</sup>